# Django password-only login

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on a project for which clients should be able to login to their account using only a single 'keycode' or password, without their username.  Security is not really an issue, as the tool is mostly for internal use. The user passwords will be inserted by an admin, so there will be no login collisions. How can I skip the username part of django's authentication and use only a keycode?

Comment: Since security is not an issue, just set the username to the same value as the password.

Comment: Good idea, but then where would I store the user's username? I need that in the screens after login

Comment: It really isn't a good idea, I was trying to point out that you really don't have any security if you don't need to know what the password relates to. Making the entire password pointless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your login you can use the username instead of password if no security is needed. Then get a form in your template and in your Django view :

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ConnexionForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data["Username"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=username)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            UserAuthentified = True
        else:
            Error = True
    else:
        Error = True
else:
    form = ConnexionForm()
```

You can get the username where you want in your template buy loading it in Django (and then use locals()):

```
request.user.username
```

Hope it answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create all users with the same (hardcoded) password and then create a view for login which receives only the passcode (I.e. the username) and re-direct it to a real login form  with the pre-defined password